# What Time Zone is used by PHAsset creationDate?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimezone, photosframework

PHAsset creationDate returns an NSDate that is constructed as if all of the photos were taken in the same "home" Time Zone.  E.g., on a given iPhone, a photo taken at 4PM in New York will have the same creationDate as one taken at 4PM in California.  This is convenient: as long as you display the date in the "home" Time Zone, it will show the local time where the photo was captured, which is usually what you want to see.  If PHAsset returned a UTC creationDate, then you would need to know what Time Zone it was captured in, which may not even be known by the iPhone, whereas the local capture time, which user wants to see anyway, is likely to be available with any photo.  So, Photos framework just reverse encodes that local time to an NSDate, using some fixed Time Zone.

Does anyone know how to determine what Time Zone the Photos framework is using for this?  Changing the iPhone settings ([NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]) does not seem to effect it, even after system reboot.  Is there a more stable system Time Zone?  Or, is this something the Photos framework is saving?

I know one way I can determine it, which is to read the photo meta data to get the local time when the photo was captured.  Then compare that to the PHAsset creationDate to see what offset was used.  But, that is pretty ugly if there is a legitimate way to query this parameter.  Or, more importantly, to know under what conditions it may change.

Here is an example of a photo taken in Australia (GMT+10) being opened on a California (GMT-7) based iPhone:

`PHAsset creationDate:      2015-03-09 22:57:35 +0000
Actual UTC capture date:   2015:03:09 05:57:34 +0000
Australian capture date:   2015:03:09 15:57:35 (GMT+10)`

Notice the PHAsset creationDate does not match the actual creation date.  Rather it is the UTC time that corresponds to 15:57:35 in California time zone.  Here is subset of metadata from the photo

`{
"{Exif}" =     {
        DateTimeDigitized = "2015:03:09 15:57:35";
     };
    "{GPS}" =     {
        DateStamp = "2015:03:09";
        TimeStamp = "05:57:34";
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        DateTime = "2015:03:09 15:57:35";
    };
}`

Comment: I find your initial assumption to be unlikely. The `creationDate` of a photo taken at 4pm in New York will likely have the same `creationDate` of a photo taken at 1pm in California. `NSDate` has no timezone. It's a fixed point in time.

Comment: Have a look at some PHAssets and see for yourself.  If it worked as you suggest, then applications would need to know what time zone a photo was taken in order to display the time the photo was taken.  Also, unless the metadata contains location or time zone information, iOS would have no way to convert the local time to any other time.  So, basically it just returns the local time the photo was taken, normalized to a fixed time zone.

Comment: No, when a photo is taken, the current `NSDate` is set as the `creationDate`. No timezone info is needed for this. If I log that date it will be correct no matter what timezone I'm in. You seem to have a basic misunderstanding about `NSDate` and what it represents. If two people, in two different timezones take a photo at the exact same physical moment (not clock time, but actual moment in time), then both assets will have the exact same creation date value. But when each of those values are viewed in the user's current timezone, they will each see the appropriate local time for that date.

Comment: No, it does not actually work that way.  If a user is looking at a photo of a sunset, they expect it to be around "7 pm" regardless of what time zone it was taken in.  So cameras generally just write the local time into the jpeg metadata.  Of course, iOS also knows your location and time zone, so in fact it does write the GMT time along with the GPS metadata.  But, the EXIF and TIFF metadata are the local time (without any timezone information).  And regardless of whether the GPS GMT time is available, PHAsset.creationTime does not return it (unless the photo was taken in the reference TZ).

Comment: You are bringing up many different aspects here. The asset's `creationDate` is the `NSDate` timestamp of when the asset is actually created. It has nothing to do with GPS or EXIF or TIFF metadata. It's essentially the UTC time the photo was taken. That can be formatted to whatever timezone you want to see whatever local time the photo was taken. If you want to see the local time of where the photo was taken then you need to get the photo's location, determine that location's timezone, and format the `NSDate` using that timezone.

Comment: You are simply wrong.  I have looked.  For photos taken in your "home" time zone, the PHAsset.creationDate is the UTC time the photo was created.  For photos taken in other time zones, it is adjusted so that if you display it in the "home" timezone it displays the local time where the photo was taken, which is what the user wants to see.  Location or time zone data is not always available, but users almost always want to see what time it was when and where they took the photo.

Comment: Where is this adjustment you are referring to? Are you talking about the date/time shown in the Photos app or are you logging the `NSDate` value of the `PHAsset`?

Comment: I am looking at the NSDate value returned by PHAsset.creationDate.  The same photo saved on 2 different iPhones with different "home" time zones will return 2 different PHAsset.creationDate values.  But they will both display the correct time the photo was taken if the NSDate is rendered in their home time zone.

Comment: I added an example to my original question, showing an actual PHAsset creationDate along with corresponding photo metadata.  If this same photo is opened on an Australian based iPhone, then the creationDate will be correct.

Comment: @maddy, you were correct for photos created on the iPhone they are being accessed on (assuming that phone has time zone set correctly when the photo is captured).  What I was seeing only occurs for photos transferred to the phone, as per my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no constant "home" timeZone, as I had guessed from examining PHAsset behavior on my phone.  When a photo is first saved, a UTC creationDate will be imputed based on the iPhone's current time zone, and the local time the photo was created (from jpeg metadata if not captured by the iPhone camera).  So, there is no constant "home" timeZone, but a different one depending on when the photo was saved.  As long as the photo was captured in the same timeZone where it is first saved to the iPhone, then the creationDate will be correct.

The behavior I was seeing only occurred because all of my photos taken in a different time zone were captured on an older iPhone and carried forward to this one.  The constant "home" time zone I saw was simply the time zone that was current when that transfer occurred.  This had nice side effect of displaying local time correctly, so I had assumed it was by design for all photos captured in different time zones.